# Apache: How can I log the total bytes transferred through a HTTP tunnel

Tags: apache, proxy, mod-proxy

I have Apache configured as a proxy.  Clients are establishing an HTTP tunnel using the CONNECT method to my Apache proxy.  I'd like to log the amount of data transferred through the HTTP tunnel.  I've tried using mod_logio's %O and %I methods but those only log the initial request and response sizes of the CONNECT request, not the subsequently tunnelled data.